# Whether there are situations when the object needs to be created in memory to a certain address?

Tags: c++, c, windows, visual-c++

Whether there are situations when the object needs to be created in memory to a certain address? Where it can be necessary (example)?

Thank you.

Comment: Implementing `std::vector`. (unless you mean exact values of addresses)

Comment: @LihO, I know about the `MyClass* x = new(ptr) MyClass(); // ptr is some pointer`variant. Where it can be need (samples)?

Comment: A memory mapped file would be an example.

Comment: @jrok, Can you explain yours answer?

Comment: Situation: There are `n` objects of `T` inside a vector `v` and there's `m*sizeof(T)` memory reserved and `m > n` holds. If you do `push_back`, you need to construct an object at the exact address `&v[0]+n`.

Comment: I took the liberty to add the tag "Windows" to this question, since Visual C++ was mentioned. The answer depends a lot on what kind of system the program is running on.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Take a look at placement new: " [What uses are there for "placement new"?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/222557/what-uses-are-there-for-placement-new) "

Good examples are writing your own memory allocator, garbage collector, or trying to precisely lay out memory due to cache performance.

It's a niche thing, but sometimes very useful.

Answer (score 0):

You seem to be asking if in a C++ application it's ever necessary to construct an object at a specific address.

Normally, no.  But there are exceptions, and the C++ language does support it.

One such exception is when building a kind of cache system for small objects in order to avoid frequent small allocations.  One would first construct a large buffer, and then when the client code wants to construct a new small object, the caching system would construct it within this large buffer.

Answer (score 0):

In C++, one may need to construct an object at a specific given address when implementing a pool allocator.  For example, Boost Pool: http://www.boost.org/doc/libs/1_47_0/libs/pool/doc/index.html